# Как реализованы паскалевские операторы parbegin parend?

Tags: ассемблер, c, pascal, многопоточность

Какие аналоги на Си или ассемблере?

Что еще хотелось бы увидеть:

- Более подробную информацию о параллельном программировании.
- Как взаимодействуют несколько ядер процессора, и почему нету коллизий?
- Только ОС следит за количеством ядер, и распределения между ними нагрузок?
- Полезные ссылки по данной теме.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Си и Ассемблере нет языковых конструкций для параллельного программирования.

Для работы с потоками см. библиотеку  pthread. Много ссылок в google. (Относительно независимая от ОС библиотека).

Параллелизм на уровне процессов (и разных узлов сети) вещь системнозависимая. Для *nix начните с fork().

Comment: В принципе я так и думал, спасибо.

Comment: ещё добавил бы библиотеку Boost..

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите ещё на OpenMP, если для вас важно обязательно поддержка на уровне языка.

О каких коллизиях вы говорите??

ОС следит за ядрами и балансирует нагрузку. Для этого в неё есть планировщик. В этом суть вытесняющей многозадачности.